# Implementing Augmented reality and 3D objects into a mobile app,

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality

I want to make a social media mobile application that utilises all the latest technologies.

This includes Augmented reality implementation.

I want to create a mobile social media platform that has the ability to add 3d objects and implement advanced augmented reality.

My question is why haven’t companies like instagram or Snapchat implemented these features?

Do devices require certain specs for these features ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data storage requirements for 3D objects on the web is insane. if you're looking to pull down data from a server that is hosting 3D model objects then some 3D objects will be well over 100 MB into the GB of data depending on the complexity. For right now, AR hasn't proven itself sufficiently worthwhile money-making wise to merit storage requirements as I explained. Also, there's the problem of the user waiting for 100 MB files to render in app and with a social media app, that's too much time to wait. Until file sizes can become smaller with compression algos and/or internet speeds ramp up 10X what they are right now, I don't see this as ever being a thing. Most apps that employ AR are downing asset packages in the background with static asset compartments or including the AR model objects in the app payload.

Comment: Ah ok. Is this why big companies like Instagram and Facebook haven’t implemented advanced AR and 3D objects ?

Comment: Would it be worth developing and releasing it onto app stores in order to make money ?

Comment: yes, @djangoninja, there's still some mystery behind AR and ppl are still injecting money into the technology even though it's utility isn't really consumer based yet. i wouldn't spent years working on an AR project, however, i would simply make a simple app, make sure you know how every aspect of it works and then launch on app store then put on resume.

Comment: Ah ok. I think I understand now. The reason companies like Instagram and Snapchat don’t implement 3d objects and advanced AR in their apps is because it will cost them a lot of money therefore they may not make a sufficient amount of profit, and it would take a long time to load 3d objects and advanced AR onto  the screen for a user in an app like a social media platform, and therefore they will lose their customers. Is all this I am saying correct ?

Comment: Also one last thing my friend, and by the way thank you for all your help. When you said "Most apps that employ AR are downing asset packages in the background with static asset compartments or including the AR model objects in the app payload."  Is this the method that Instagram and snapchat are currently using when implementing advanced AR and 3D objects into their applications?

Comment: @djangoninja i'm not exactly sure what they are doing, but i'm fairly certain there is a way to wrap asset packages and host them somewhere on web for ios to interface with them without needing to reinstall the full app again. i think this was a major update to ios within the last few years if i'm not mistaken. i'll look through the docs later to see what i can find. but if you look at total memory storage for mobile games, some exceed 1 GB of stored data. that's not the app payload, those are 2D/3D assets

Comment: Ah Ok. I have attempted to research into instagram and snapchat, and see how they implement AR, however I couldn't find anything. And please let me know as soon as you find something in the docs relating to this. Thank you.